# Windows Server 2022 unable to logon due to no Remote Desktop License Servers available

Tags: windows, active-directory, rdp, windows-server-2022

### Summary

I need to allow Windows Server 2022 to allow unique users to RDP to the server at the same time. I believe this was the default behavior that was working for about a month, before the error below appeared and RDP stopped working. What do I need to do to get this behavior back?

### Background

I was tasked for providing Web RDP access to a Windows Server 2022 machine. After attempting and failing to do so solely with Window's RDP capabilities, I (at least thought I) reverted all RDP services and got something working with Apache Guacamole. When working the machine was an AD Server, but is the only machine being managed.

Fast forward a month or so and now no one can RDP to this server. Even using the typical Windows RDP client gives you the following error:

```
[Window Title]
Remote Desktop Connection

[Content]
The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote Desktop License Servers available to provide a license.
Please contact the server administrator.

[^] Hide details  [OK]

[Expanded Information]
Error code: 0x808
Extended error code: 0x101
```

All the help documents mention an RD License Server but I did not have that installed when everything was working. See configuration below:

[image]

What changes need to be made to get this working like it used to?

Comment: At a minimum, the Remote Desktop License role must be installed, configured, and activated. Microsoft has detailed procedures here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-activate-license-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the help documents mention an RD License Server but I did not have
> that installed when everything was working.

Your server need licence to give to the user that login. If your user(s) were working before, it's because they were probably local admin or they got issued temporary licence. The local admin right to RDP-in is to administer the server, thus which is not the case for you.

In both case you are in not legal status because you don't have licence for your users to log in. You would fail a Microsoft audit.

To resolve your issue get RDS-CAL (per users or devices) and apply them to a RD License server. (and point your broker to that licence server)